# Swagger UI not Displaying Models

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

Swagger UI is not displaying models after adding the attribute `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` on my api actions.

Before adding the attribute `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]`on my api actions I was able to see the models / schema in the swagger UI.

This is how I have configured swagger

**Startup.cs**
*ConfigureServices*

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = "My Working API",
                    Description = "All Information related to API",
                });

                // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });
```

*Configure*

```
app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                string swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
                c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1");
            });
            app.UseStaticFiles();
```

**DBContext**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class MyDBContext: DbContext
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// My Product DB
        /// </summary>
        public MyDBContext()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// My Product information DB
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="options"></param>
        public MyDBContext(DbContextOptions<MyDBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Product Model
        /// </summary>
        public virtual DbSet<Product> Product{ get; set; }

    }
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I think that the `IgnoreApi` is doing what is supposed to

Comment: I didn't add IgnoreApi to the models.

Comment: what do you think will happen to those models used in the api action that have the `IgnoreApi`

Comment: If that is the case then there should be a way to display the models explicitly.

Comment: Look into `IDocumentFilter` you might be able to inject models explicitly that way

Answer (score 3):

For Swagger to show the "Schemas" (Models) you need to use it in code.

**Before:** *[Member object not used within API route]*

[image]
[image]

**After:** *[Member object used within API route]*

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was dumb to not add the the getters and setters to the Model Class. So Swagger could not access the properties. It could be the same with you or other Googlers.